# How to get the hash code of a Javascript implemented interface

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have an interface, EventHandler (OSGi EventAdmin), with a single method handleEvent(Event).

I have the following Javascript code:

```
importPackage(org.osgi.service.event)

obj =
{
    handleEvent: function(event)
    {
        // some code
    }
};

handler = new EventHandler(obj);

service.registerHandler(handler, topic);
```

The code is executed by Rhino (more specifically Rhino as built into JRE6, JSR-223 spec). 
service is a Java object bound to the script context where registerHandler first looks up the handler in a Map.  This fails because the NativeObject "handler"
doesn't have a hashCode() method.

Is there a reason a NativeObject is missing standard Java Object methods?

What's a way to work around this?

I'm using Rhino that comes with JRE6 (1.6R2).

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complete, but `NativeObject` looks more like a *JavaScript* object to me.

Comment: I updated code, only missing import statement. As I understand it, 'code'NativeObject is the Javascript representation of a Java object.  EventHandler is an interface so the object created is a special object.  Is there a way to create a Java object instead?